# Return multiple strings from function based on variable number

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

I have a string

```
var str = 'string'
```

I have a multiplier

```
var mult = 3
```

I want to return `stringstringstring`

The mult will change. Basically mult is kind of like a power but this is a string not a number. And I need to return multiple strings. I'm thinking of looping where mult = the number of times to loop and each would conceptually 'push' but I don't want an array or something like =+ but not a number. I'm thinking I could have the output push to an array the number of times = to mult, and then join the array - but I don't know if join is possible without a delimiter. I'm new at javascript and the below doesn't work but it's what I'm thinking. There's also no ability to input a function in the place I'm running javascript and also no libraries.

```
var loop = {
  var str = 'string'
  var arr = [];
  var mult = 3;
  var i = 0
  for (i = 0, mult-1, i++) {
    arr.push('string'[i]);
  }
}
var finalString = arr.join(''); // I don't know how to get it out of an object first before joining
```

Not sure if what I want is ridiculous or if it's at all possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like below,

```js
var str = 'string'
var mult = 3
var str2 = ''
for(i = 0; i < mult; i++) {
    str2 += str
}
console.log(str2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = 'string'
var mult = 3;
var sol =""
while(mult--) {
   sol +=str;
}
console.log(sol)
```

Using resusable function:

```js
const concatStr= (str, mult)=>{
  var sol =""
  while(mult--) {
 sol +=str;
  }
  console.log(sol)
}

concatStr("string",3)
```

Using the inbuilt `Array.from` method:

```js
var str = "string"
var mult = 3
var sol = Array.from({length: mult}, ()=> str).join("")
console.log(sol)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function concatString(str, mult) {
   var result = ''
   for(i = 0; i < mult; i++) {
      result = result.concat(str);
   }
    return result;
 }

const value = concatString('string', 3);
console.log(value);
```

Also you can use array inbuilt methods,

```
const mult = 3, displayVal = 'str';
Array(mult).fill(displayVal).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// the string object has a repeat method
console.log('string'.repeat(3));
```